# StackOverflowException на set

Tags: c#

```
class RequestForm
    {
        public long UserID { get { return UserID; } set { RequestMode = Mode.FullName; UserID = value; } }
        public string FullName { get { return FullName; } set { RequestMode = Mode.GroupNumber; FullName = value; } }
        public int GroupNumber { get { return GroupNumber; } set { RequestMode = Mode.Count; GroupNumber = value; } }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        private Mode _requestMode = Mode.FullName;
        public Mode RequestMode
        {
            get
            {
                return _requestMode;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_requestMode != value)
                    _requestMode = value;
            }
        }

        public enum Mode
        {
            FullName,
            GroupNumber,
            Count
        }

        public RequestForm(long UserID)
        {
            this.UserID = UserID;
        }
    }
```

Выдаёт ошибку StackOverflowException на set свойства RequestMode.
Перепробовал всё (создание private поля, просто get;set;), не помогает. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Мало просто создать private-поле, надо ещё в геттере и сеттере использовать именно его

Comment: Я имел ввиду это. Не помогает.

Comment: Покажите как пробовали. Код выкладывайте текстом, а не картинкой только.

Comment: private Mode _requestMode = Mode.FullName;
public Mode RequestMode
        {
            get
            {
                return _requestMode;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_requestMode != value)
                    _requestMode = value;
            }
        }

Comment: И что? Этот код бросает StackOverflowException?

Comment: Да, только уже на set.

Comment: Не верю. Отредактируйте вопрос, приведите код минимального самодостаточного примера для воспроизведения проблемы. В виде текста.

Comment: Жду ваших предложений.

Comment: Как думаете, что здесь происходит: `long UserID { get { return UserID; } ...`?

Comment: Вам надо создать backing field для **каждого** вашего свойства, иначе этот топик никогда не найдет завершения.

Comment: а я-то думаю что я вроде на такой отвечал...